# Desktop icons are duplicated on both screens

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, 17.04

My desktop is extended on two screens, the right one (DP-1) set as the main one. Displays settings :

[image]

But as it can be seen below, the desktop icons are duplicated (they show on both screens) :

[image]

Although the screens are *not* mirrored (you can see that the opened window is only displayed on the right, as expected).

- If I add/remove something on the desktop, the corresponding icon shows/disappears on the other screen.
- If I move an icon to another place, the change is *not* reflected on the other screen.

Apart from that, everything works as intended ; I can move windows from one screen to another, and so on.

Is there any settings I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

In the "desktop settings" for the monitor you don't want to be duplicated, switch between "folder" and "desktop" view. It worked for me.

Comment: Where are these settings?